# would create a cyclic reference AWS-CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I trying to launch VPN stack with a GOOGLE SAML xml file as a provider attached to it. The error we have is not really clear to us.

We're using the version v2.12.0 of the aws-cdk :

```
from aws_cdk import CfnOutput, Stack
import aws_cdk.aws_iam as iam
import aws_cdk.aws_ec2 as ec2
from constructs import Construct
​
class CdkVpnStack(Stack):
​
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, vpc, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
​
        provider = iam.SamlProvider(self, "Google",
                            metadata_document=iam.SamlMetadataDocument.from_file("pki/GoogleIDPMetadata.xml")
                        )
​
        endpoint = vpc.add_client_vpn_endpoint("VPN Endpoint",
            cidr="10.100.0.0/16",
            server_certificate_arn="arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:0000000000:certificate/cd48035c-b70e-47c5-9615-af0eaf75121f",
            user_based_authentication=ec2.ClientVpnUserBasedAuthentication.federated(provider),
            authorize_all_users_to_vpc_cidr=False,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_group_name="Public")
        )
​
        endpoint.add_authorization_rule("Rule",
            cidr=vpc.vpc_cidr_block
        )
​
        CfnOutput(self, "Output",
                        value=endpoint.endpoint_id)
```

and getting this error

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  Error: 'vpn-vpc' depends on 'vpn-vpn' (vpn-vpc -> vpn-vpn/Google/Resource.Ref). Adding this dependency (vpn-vpn -> vpn-vpc/vpn-sbx-vpc/VPN Endpoint/Resource.Ref) would create a cyclic reference.
      at Stack._addAssemblyDependency (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/stack.js:1:6887)
      at Object.addDependency (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/deps.js:1:926)
      at Stack.addDependency (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/stack.js:1:4818)
      at resolveValue (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/refs.js:1:1683)
      at Object.resolveReferences (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/refs.js:1:627)
      at Object.prepareApp (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/prepare-app.js:1:564)
      at Object.synthesize (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/synthesis.js:1:557)
      at App.synth (/tmp/jsii-kernel-o8ekVH/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/stage.js:1:1853)
      at /tmp/tmpvzkfodb1/lib/program.js:8228:134
      at Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (/tmp/tmpvzkfodb1/lib/program.js:8840:24)
```